# Null createConnection in Tomcat 7 when trying to connect to a Derby Network database

Tags: java, tomcat7, database-connection, derby

I'm trying to secure Tomcat's manager access using a Derby Network Database. For this purpose I created a Derby Network Database with all the necessary.

Here is my server.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  
  <Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener"/>
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>

  <GlobalNamingResources>

    <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
                
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" name="jdbc/***" password="***" readOnly="false" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527//***" username="***" validationQuery="SELECT count(*) FROM users"/>
    
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">

    <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>

    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>
    
    <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">

           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm" dataSourceName="jdbc/***" debug="0" digest="MD5" roleNameCol="ROLENAME" userCredCol="PASSWORD" userNameCol="USERNAME" userRoleTable="***" userTable="USERS"/>

        <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">


        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"/>

      <Context docBase="***" path="***" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:tds"/></Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

And my context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Context>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <ResourceLink global="jdbc/***" name="jdbc/***" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</Context>
```

derbyclient.jar, derbynet.jar, derby.jar are in $Tomcat directory$/libs

When I initialize tomcat everything seems to be OK but if I try to access to the manager it returns the following error:

```
ene 26, 2015 4:58:56 PM org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm open
SEVERE: Exception performing authentication
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection factory returned null from createConnection
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:584)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm.open(DataSourceRealm.java:388)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm.authenticate(DataSourceRealm.java:284)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicAuthenticator.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:573)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
```

Maybe is something missing? I don't know what I'm doing wrong because I checked a similar config I have in a production server and there is no difference. Obiously the Derby network DB is initialized (I can open it with squirrel)

I'd appreciate any contribution

Edit:

The config was OK but I had an error in the resource URL jdbc:derby://localhost:1527//C:***\derbydb --> jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/C:***\derbydb

Hope my configuration can be useful to someone.